# Reading an XML file and create a list of objects that match the XML content

Tags: c#, xml, linq, parsing

I have an XML file that contains some information regarding what components are installed on a specific computer, and what configuration files that belong to each component.

A development example of the file looks like this:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<ConfigMappings>

  <Host Name="Host1">
    <Component Name="AlarmManager" Version="1.0.1.0" Enabled="True">
      <Config Name="AlarmManager.Configuration.xml" Version="1.0.0.0" SubFolder=""/>
      <Config Name="faultMapConfig.xml" Version="1.0.0.0" SubFolder=""/>
      <Config Name="LoadsCalculatorConfig.xml" Version="1.0.0.0" SubFolder="Advisory"/>
    </Component>
  </Host>

<Host Name="Host2">
    <Component Name="AdvisoryManager" Version="1.0.1.0" Enabled="True">
      <Config Name="DeviceManager.Configuration.xml" Version="1.0.0.1" SubFolder=""/>
      <Config Name="BasicData.xml" Version="1.0.0.2" SubFolder="Advisory"/>
      <Config Name="BasicData.xsd" Version="1.0.0.3" SubFolder="Advisory"/>
      <Config Name="Utilization.xml" Version="1.0.0.4" SubFolder=""/>
      <Config Name="Utilization.xsd" Version="1.0.0.4" SubFolder=""/>
      <Config Name="faultMapConfig.xsd" Version="1.0.0.4" SubFolder=""/>
      <Config Name="faultMapConfig.xml" Version="1.0.0.4" SubFolder=""/>
    </Component>
    <Component Name="w32time" Version="1.0.1.0" Enabled="True">
       <Config Name="DeviceManager.Configuration.xml" Version="1.0.0.1" SubFolder=""/>
    </Component>
  </Host>    
</ConfigMappings>
```

What i want to do is to read this XML file and where i find a Host element that matches my computers hostname. I want to create a list of Components that contain the Name, Version and Enabled properties + a list of its Configs (Name, Version, Subfolder).

I've managed to achieve this on my own doing this:

```
var xdoc = XDocument.Load(dlg.FileName);
var components =
    from c in xdoc.Descendants("Component")
    where
        String.Equals(c.Parent.Attribute("Name").Value, Environment.MachineName, StringComparison.CurrentCultureIgnoreCase)
    select new
    {
        Name = c.Attribute("Name").Value,
        Enabled = c.Attribute("Enabled").Value,
        version = c.Attribute("Version").Value,
    };

ComponentList.Clear();
foreach (var component in components)
{
    bool componentEnable = component != null && component.Enabled == "True";
    ComponentList.Add(new Component(component.Name, componentEnable, component.version));
}

foreach (var component in ComponentList)
{
    var configs =
    from c in xdoc.Descendants("Config")
    where 
    c.Parent.Parent.Name == "Host" &&
    String.Equals(c.Parent.Parent.Attribute("Name").Value, Environment.MachineName, StringComparison.CurrentCultureIgnoreCase) &&
    String.Equals(c.Parent.Attribute("Name").Value, component.Name, StringComparison.CurrentCultureIgnoreCase)
    select new
    {
        Name = c.Attribute("Name").Value,
        version = c.Attribute("Version").Value,
        SubFolder = c.Attribute("SubFolder").Value,
    };

    foreach (var config in configs)
    {
        component.Configurations.Add(new Config(config.Name, config.version, config.SubFolder));
    }
}
```

Here ComponentList is a List of Components. And Component is a class that contains its attributes (Name, Version and Enabled) + a list of configurations objects.

Now this works. But it seems like a very cluttered and messy way to do this and i'd like some help to improve this.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
namespace ConsoleApplication3
{
    using System;
    using System.Collections.Generic;
    using System.Diagnostics;
    using System.Linq;
    using System.Net;
    using System.Text;
    using System.Threading.Tasks;
    using System.Xml.Linq;

 public class Config
        {
            public string Name { get; set; }
            public string Version { get; set; }
            public string SubFolder { get; set; }
        }

    public class Component
    {
        public List<Config> SystemConfig;
        public string Name { get; set; }
        public string Version { get; set; }
        public string Enabled { get; set; }
        public Component()
        {

            this.SystemConfig = new List<Config>();
        }
    }

    public class Program
    {

        public static void Main()
        {
            XDocument xmlDocument = XDocument.Load(@"c:\Visual Studio\Projects\ConsoleApplication3\ConsoleApplication3\config.xml");
            var item = (from template in xmlDocument.Descendants("Component")
                        where template.Parent.Attribute("Name").Value.Equals("Host1", StringComparison.CurrentCultureIgnoreCase)
                        select new Component()
                        {
                            Version = template.Attribute("Version").Value,
                            Name = template.Attribute("Name").Value,
                            Enabled = template.Attribute("Enabled").Value,
                            SystemConfig = (
                               from t in template.Elements("Config")
                               select new Config()
                               {
                                   Name = t.Attribute("Name").Value,
                                   SubFolder = t.Attribute("SubFolder").Value,
                                   Version = t.Attribute("Version").Value
                               }
                               ).ToList()
                        }
                                 ).FirstOrDefault();
        }
    }
}
```

Please feel free to remove hard coded value. The above code will give you the first object where Host name is matched.

Comment: Removing .FirstOrDefault() in the query and doing an Item.ToList() this got me the result i wanted :)

The metodology is similar to what i attempted on my own, but the code is much cleaner and to the point.

Thanks for the help!

Answer (score 0):

Not sure if this helps but to read an XML I usually use a code like this:

```
XmlDocument doc = new XmlDocument();
doc.Load(pathOfYourXmlDocument);
```

Then you can do something like this:

```
XmlElement root= doc["ConfigMappings"];
```

Then you can select other Nodes like this:

```
XmlNode host= root.SelectSingleNode("Host1"); 
XmlNode component = host.SelectSingleNode("Component");
```

And finally create a list of all subnodes of component like this:

```
XmlNodeList configList = component.SelectNodes("Config");
```

Now you can iterate trough the XmlNodeList and get Innertexts, Attributes or whatever you need. Not sure if this helps you and there clearly is no right or false way just different solutions where some may be pretty, some may be efficient and some might be both. This is the way I read Xml-files and work with them but there are many more possibilities.

Answer (score 0):

If you have POCO, then you can write (Note string extention to Deserialize xml ([source](https://gist.github.com/margusmartsepp/23c71cdbc6935fd18d90))):

```
ConfigMappings item;
if(File.ReadAllText(@"d:\in.csv").Deserialize(out item)){
  //item is loaded
}
```

To get POCO <kbd>copy</kbd> & <kbd>paste special</kbd> - <kbd>as xml classes</kbd> (min VS2012.2 RC).

```
[System.Xml.Serialization.XmlTypeAttribute(AnonymousType = true)]
[System.Xml.Serialization.XmlRootAttribute(Namespace = "", IsNullable = false)]
public partial class ConfigMappings {
    [System.Xml.Serialization.XmlElementAttribute("Host")]
    public ConfigMappingsHost[] Host { get; set; }
}
[System.Xml.Serialization.XmlTypeAttribute(AnonymousType = true)]
public partial class ConfigMappingsHost {
    [System.Xml.Serialization.XmlElementAttribute("Component")]
    public ConfigMappingsHostComponent[] Component { get; set; }
    [System.Xml.Serialization.XmlAttributeAttribute()]
    public string Name { get; set; }
}
[System.Xml.Serialization.XmlTypeAttribute(AnonymousType = true)]
public partial class ConfigMappingsHostComponent {
    [System.Xml.Serialization.XmlElementAttribute("Config")]
    public ConfigMappingsHostComponentConfig[] Config { get; set; }
    [System.Xml.Serialization.XmlAttributeAttribute()]
    public string Name { get; set; }
    [System.Xml.Serialization.XmlAttributeAttribute()]
    public string Version { get; set; }
    [System.Xml.Serialization.XmlAttributeAttribute()]
    public string Enabled { get; set; }
}
[System.Xml.Serialization.XmlTypeAttribute(AnonymousType = true)]
public partial class ConfigMappingsHostComponentConfig {
    [System.Xml.Serialization.XmlAttributeAttribute()]
    public string Name { get; set; }
    [System.Xml.Serialization.XmlAttributeAttribute()]
    public string Version { get; set; }
    [System.Xml.Serialization.XmlAttributeAttribute()]
    public string SubFolder { get; set; }
}
```

Comment: This works for reading in the entire content of the XML. But i'm only after that parts that are specific to me. I only want the Components and Configurations where the <Host Name="Host1"> is equal to the my computers hostname.

Would it be possible to do a simple filtring of XML first to find the element where <Host Name="Host1"> fits my computers hostname. Then read everything that belongs to that element into a string?

Then make it Deserialize into my preexisting classes by marking those with similar [System.Xml.Serialization.XmlElementAttribute("")] attributes?

Comment: Because now i get an object that contains all host with their Components and Configurations. While i want a list of Components and configurations for my one specific host :)